# How can I modify a part of bigger slice or Vec with another smaller slice?

Tags: rust, slice

How can I correctly implement this code below?

```rust
let mut bigger: [u8; 100] = [0u8; 100];
let smaller: [u8; 3] = [1, 2, 3];

// do something like: 
// bigger[0..3] = smaller;
```

Comment: In addition, without using a loop, is there any sugar in Rust to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`copy_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice):

```
bigger[0..3].copy_from_slice(&smaller);
```

<sup>[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba50829f1aca214c1f29a7a4f64a8b37)</sup>